Is there a way to get notifications when a dag fails to render and "DAG seems to be missing"?
I have my dags set to send me notifications inside the dag (using a task to send slack messages) if the dag fails. I even have alerts set up for the webserver health etc.  But I am not going to the webserver all the time, so certain errors which prevent the dag from being "seen" can go unnoticed until I go look at the airflow UI.  It would be extremely useful to have the ability to send an alert when a dag is broken so badly that it fails to render, but I'm at a loss as to how to do that.
Maybe this is something gcloud could do?  Maybe I could create a separate dag that looks for dagbag errors?  But that would be a task in something like a bash script and I don't know how to do that.  I am hoping maybe airflow has a configuration I can set to get alerts?
This is an example of the kind of error I'm talking about - where the dag is no longer in the dagbag and not visible in the airflow ui.  
I am on composer-2.6.3-airflow-2.6.3

Why don't you use Cloud Logging and write the query that catches the errors you are looking for? Using the custom query, you can create an alert and send an email only to the relevant teams/people.
